# Cyberduck shows all word documents as .url files in google drive

Tags: cyberduck

I was able to download and install the Cyberduck software.
I can see the files listed after connecting to google drive using the cyberduck (cyberduck.io), but all my word documents are listed as .url files
Any idea why this is so? I want to download these word documents but when I do, it only downloads as an .url file.
Please help

Comment: IIRC - it's been about a year since I tinkered with Drive - but this is because Google Drive is basically storing *pointers* to the actual Google Docs versions of these files. There aren't actual `.doc` files to be had.

Comment: If they are pointers then how do I download them? I mean download them via Cyberduck